# Can I play AOE 2 over LAN, cross-platform, between Mac and Windows?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

A few friends and I want to play some AOE over the weekend.  I have a MacBook Air, and they have PC's running Windows XP.  They are all able to connect to a single host using the "Local Area Network" option in multiplayer, however, I cannot connect to a host running Windows.

I am unable to locate any option which says "LAN" in the multiplayer screen.  Also, even though we're all connected to the same router and have IPs like 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, etc, I can't directly connect over TCP/IP using their IP address.

I have Googled for this and have seen posts saying that AOE II does not support cross platform multi-player gaming. I know this is a long shot, but does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Hamachi to connect two computers in LAN and download a program called aoe loader. Open the aoe loader and select the hamachi IP and try playing the game. This worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I could bet that works, but, after search the web, I found that doesn't.

I found something here: http://destineergames.com/support/?page_id=35

> Unfortunately, we are unable to offer support for cross-platform,
>   multiplayer gaming at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Playing Age of Empires 2 cross-platform between a PC (Windows 7) and a Mac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite) *works* -- at least if you also play the PC version through Wine on the Mac. Have successfully done this today, playing a two-player game on the same (W)LAN.

In our case, the PC was the game host, and the Mac joined.

## Steps on the Windows (game host) machine

- Install AoE 2.
- [Make sure the right ports are open](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/895864). "Allowing the application" in Windows Firewall should be enough (assuming there no other firewalls have been installed).
- Start the game and create a multiplayer LAN game. Wait for the Mac.

## Steps on the Mac (game participant) machine

- [Get Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/), create a new Wineskin wrapper application, and install AoE 2.
- [Install DirectPlay through WineTricks](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4184&iTestingId=51395). This is preferably done through the Wineskin wrapper's advanced options, reachable by holding <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> when starting the wrapper. Then click Advanced, Tools, Winetricks, find DirectPlay in the list(s) and hit "run".
- Start the game using the wrapper. If all has gone well, the game created on the Windows machine should show up in the list of LAN games on the Mac.
- Join and enjoy!

---

We were of course making sure we ran the same version/patch of the game on both machines. Haven't tried it yet, but have read good things about the ambitious [UserPatch](http://userpatch.aiscripters.net/), which both fixes bugs and improves the game in general.